# Using an extension method without calling class name

Tags: c#, class, extension-methods

I'm trying to create a static(global) function that I can call from within any script in my project using an extension method, but I don't think I am implementing it properly.

file:extensions.cs

```
namespace CustomExtensions
{
  public static class MathExt
  {
    public static float Remap (float value, float from1, float to1, float from2, float to2)
    {
      return (((value - from1) * (to2 - from2) / (to1 - from1)) + from2);
    }
  }
}
```

Now from within another file I am want to be able to use this syntax:

```
using CustomExtensions;

public class MySound
{
  public void SetPitch(float rpm)
  {
    pitch = Remap(rpm, minRPM, maxRPM, 0.5f, 1.5f);
  }
}
```

However I get an error unless I do `MathExt.Remap(rpm, 720, maxRPM, .75f, 1.75f);`

I also tried `using CustomExtensions.MathExt;` but it still threw an error out.

I would like to call this function without having to declare MathExt before it. I realize that it's simple enough to just add the classname, but I want to understand what I am doing incorrectly.

Comment: Whixch error DO you get when calling `MathExt.Remap(rpm, 720, maxRPM, .75f, 1.75f);`?

Comment: @HimBromBeere I get `The name 'Remap' does not exist in the current context`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not an extension method. You didn't define the object that is the base for the extension method (you do that using `this`):

```
public static float Remap (this float value, float from1, float to1, float from2, float to2)
{ }
```

Then you call it:

```
pitch = rpm.Remap(minRPM, maxRPM, 0.5f, 1.5f);
```

Comment: Thought I might have been doing that incorrectly. How could I instead use it as a static function as my last example shows?

Comment: Then the class should be the same, or use the solution from David.

Answer (score 4):

if you are using C#6 you can try and use

```
using static CustomExtensions.MathExt;
```

[Link](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6#using-static)

Comment: Gave that a shot but it said `Identifier expected, static is a keyword`

Comment: @ViperCode What version of C# are you using? It only works with C#6 (as per David's comment)

Comment: @MatthewWatson Figured that was most likely the issue, I'm still on .NET 3.5 I believe with the project so not C#6 yet, which is why it doesn't work.

Comment: @ViperCode The version of C# and the version of .Net aren't strictly linked. You can use C#6 with .Net3.5 - but you need Visual Studio 2015

Comment: Ok found the info, it's C#5, gunna look into upping to C#6 for this. Thought I was doing something wrong but it's just the limitation of the version. Good to know at least, Thanks!